# I cannot figure out why my ajax is not sending the data to my php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with my Ajax. It seems to not be sending the data to my php file even though it worked properly 2 days ago. HTML:

```
<form id='comment' action='process.php' method="POST">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button type='submit'>Comment</button> 
</form>
```

My ajax code:

```
$('#comment').submit(function(event) {

    var form = $(this);
    var method = form.attr('method');
    var url = form.attr('action');

    info = {
        comment: $('textarea').val()
    };

    console.log(method);
    console.log(url);
    console.log(info);

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: info,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm doing this for a friend and I'm using this exact same Ajax code (slightly modified) on my website and it's working flawlessly.
I think the biggest red flag here is that in my php file I have an if-else that should send an alert in case the textarea is empty but for some reason it's not doing that here even though nothing is getting through. I used console.log on all the variables to see if their values are correct and they are. The alert(data) just returns an empty alert box.

EDIT: As requested, PHP code from process.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'db_connection.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zagreb');

if(isset($_POST['comment'])){

function SQLInsert($id, $date, $komentar, $conn){
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (user, date, comment) VALUES ('$id', '$date', 
'$comment')";
$conn -> query($sql);
$conn -> close();
}

$id = $_SESSION['username'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);

SQLInsert($id, $date, $komentar, $conn);

} else {
echo '<script>';
echo 'alert("Comment box is empty.");';
echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

EDIT: Problem solved, thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: try to change button type="submit" with button type="button"

Comment: Do you strictly need to use ajax? Why do not you just use HTML to submit a form?

Comment: What is in the process.php script?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working in your case? Is the data sent properly (that can be seen in the network tab of your browser)?

Comment: Check your route is correct

Comment: Do you have another textarea on the page? If yes, try comment: $(this).find('textarea').val() - to get only textarea located in the form

Comment: The exact problem I have is that my console logs are showing that everything is okay but once the alert(data) gets executed it's showing that it's empty AKA nothing is being sent. I don't have any other textareas on the page. My php script just takes the variables and saves it in a database. Also I need to use ajax since I'm doing this for a project and at least one form with ajax must be included.

Comment: add this code'error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }'  after 'success' and write here the error you are getting

Comment: does your php scripts return anything. if yes you will be able to see in `alert(data)` if not then nothing gets printed.

Comment: I tried no issue in code. It's working fine. how you are getting ajax data and display the response in process.php file? Please add the code of process.php  file.

Comment: The best tool to debug this really is the network tab in the browser console...

Comment: What should I be looking for in the network tab?

Comment: Firstly try Network tab to see if ajax has headers you need, and if there is any return from PHP. Secondly use `var_dump($_POST)` to show whole $_POST variable to see if there wasn't any misspell or incorrect nesting of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are no getting alert because you are no displaying anything as response in php file. Add the insert function out side the if condition too

```
 function SQLInsert($id, $date, $komentar, $conn){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (user, date, comment) VALUES ('$id', '$date', 
    '$comment')";

    if($conn -> query($sql)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    $conn -> close();
}

if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
    $id = $_SESSION['username'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);

    $insert = SQLInsert($id, $date, $komentar, $conn);

     //On based on insert display the response. After that you will get alert message in ajax
    if($insert){
        echo 'insert sucess';
        die;
    }else{
        echo 'Error Message';
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did figure that out. Using var_dump($_POST) does seem like the PHP is getting the values from it. I did resolve the issue, I was looking in a completely wrong section. The problem was with my SQL table, the column used for storing comments is different that what I wrote in the SQL statement in my PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='comment' action='process.php' method="POST">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <button id="submit_button">Comment</button> 
</form>
```

starting from this html you have to trigger your function as:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(e){
```

I have added an id to your button for simplicity and removed the type because it is useless in this case.

If you want to catch the submit event of the form you have to change your html as:

```
<form id='comment' action='process.php' method="POST">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type='submit'>Comment</button> 
</form>
```

and then you can keep the same javascript

Comment: I tried doing this but somehow this made things a whole lot worse. Instead of capturing just the textarea value, the alert(data) returned the entire HTML code and the console showed 2 objects.

Comment: That depends on what you have in your php side. But your issue firing the form is solved. If you show your php we can debug that too

Answer (score 0):

This here is the issue. Have you tried providing a "method" ?

```
  $.ajax({
        **type: method,**
        method : method,
        url: url,
        data: info,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Also if this doesn't solve it. show me the console output

Answer (score 0):

```
       <form  name="fileInfoForm"  id='comment' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$('#comment').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var textarea=$('#textarea').val();
   var form=document.getElementById('comment');
        var fd=new FormData(form);
        fd.append('textarea',textarea);
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

            url: 'action.php',
            data: fd,
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
alert(data);
            }


        })


});
</script>



in action.php
           $textarea= $_POST['textarea'];
    echo $textarea;
```

Comment: from echo $textarea you can check data is posted and in your php file create an response array like $response=array(); and add $response['textarea']=$textarea;

Comment: in the end of your php file     echo json_encode($response);